# Constructing a sequence of function with bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ be a smooth function and analytic at $x=0$. I wish to find a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is convergent to $f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f'''_n$ is bounded. I know, we could take the Taylor polynomial if there was no condition $f'''_n$. However, this boundedness rises the difficulty of my problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you require $f_n$ to have uniformly bounded third derivative with respect to $n$?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: Yes, any suggestion?

Comment: Any sequence of cubic polynomials with bounded leading coefficient will do, won't it ?

Comment: What's wrong with letting $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for $|x|<n$ and let this smoothly "fade out" to something linear?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: but $f$ is not necessary a polynomial

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It seems to be true. But, what "fade out" do you mean?

Comment: @Jlamprong, do you mean that $f$ is a given and has an unbounded third derivative?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, it is given.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: $f$ is given but not knowing to have bounded or unbounded third derivative

Comment: @Jlamprong "fade out": Let $\phi\colon \mathbb R\to [0,1]$ be smooth with $\phi(x)=1$ for $|x|\le 1$, $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|\ge 2$. Let $h_n(x)= f'''(x)\phi(x/n)$ and integrate it a few times with suitable integration constants to obtain $f_n(x)$. Then $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for $|x|\le n$ and $f_n'''(x)=0$ for $|x|\ge 2n$ (though this "fades out" to a polynomial, not a line)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, my version of your question: Take $f$ a  function, say continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, analytic at $x=0$. You want to show that there exists a sequence $f_n$ of functions, say $\in C^3(\mathbb{R})$, such that for all fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, and that there exists $M>0$, such that for all $n$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $|f_n^{(3)}(x)|\leq M$. (See your answer to ChristopherA.Wong comment)

If this is your question, I think that additionnal hypothesis are needed.

To see why, let $\alpha_k$ be constants, not all zero, such that $\alpha_0+\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=0$, and $\alpha_1+2\alpha_2+3\alpha_3=\alpha_1+2^2\alpha_2+3^2\alpha_3=0$.

We have for $t=1,2,3$ that there exists $c_t\in \mathbb{R}$ (depending on $h,x,n..$) such that:
$$f_n(x+th)=f_n(x)+thf_n^{\prime}(x)+\frac{t^2h^2}{2}f_n^{\prime\prime}(x)+\frac{t^3h^3}{6}f_n^{(3)}(c_t)$$

We get:
$$\alpha_0 f_n(x)+\alpha_1 f_n(x+h)+\alpha_2 f_n(x+2h)+\alpha_3f(x+3h)=(\alpha_1f_n^{(3)}(c_1)+2^3f_n^{(3)}(c_2)+3^3\alpha_3f_n^{(3)}(c_3))\frac{h^3}{6}$$
Now, by the hypothesis, there exists $M_1$ independant of $n,x,h$, such that for all $n$, $x$ and $h$:
$$|\alpha_0 f_n(x)+\alpha_1 f_n(x+h)+\alpha_2 f_n(x+2h)+\alpha_3f_n(x+3h)|\leq M_1|h|^3$$

and if $n\to +\infty$ we get:
$$|\alpha_0 f(x)+\alpha_1 f(x+h)+\alpha_2 f(x+2h)+\alpha_3f(x+3h)|\leq M_1|h|^3$$
for all $x$ and $h$. You can see that this condition is not satisfied by $f(x)=\exp(x)$ for example.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. So, we need some extra conditions, don't we?